# JPA exception: Object: ... is not a known entity type

Tags: java, jpa, toplink

I'm new to JPA and I'm having problems with the autogeneration of primary key values.

I have the following entity:

```
package jpatest.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    private String someProperty;

    public String getSomeProperty() {
        return someProperty;
    }

    public void setSomeProperty(String someProperty) {
        this.someProperty = someProperty;
    }

    public MyEntity() {
    }

    public MyEntity(String someProperty) {
        this.someProperty = someProperty;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "jpatest.entities.MyEntity[id=" + id + "]";
    }    
}
```

and the following main method in other class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JPATestPU");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    em.getTransaction().begin();

    MyEntity e = new MyEntity("some value");    
    em.persist(e); /* (exception thrown here) */

    em.getTransaction().commit();

    em.close();
    emf.close();
}
```

This is my persistence unit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="JPATestPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>jpatest.entities.MyEntity</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="toplink.jdbc.user" value="..."/>
      <property name="toplink.jdbc.password" value="..."/>
      <property name="toplink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jpatest"/>
      <property name="toplink.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="toplink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

When I execute the program I get the following exception in the line marked with the proper comment:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: jpatest.entities.MyEntity[id=null] is not a known entity type.
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3212)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.base.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:205)
        at jpatest.Main.main(Main.java:...)
```

**What am I missing?**

Comment: I was override toString method and faced with a same method may it is because you are previously using this class without overriding toString method as my experience

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TopLink used to require you to explicitly set **GenerationType.IDENTITY** for MySQL, so change this and drop the database. Then try running your sample again. Further you might also want to explcitly set the database platform:

```
 <property name="toplink.platform.class.name" 
                    value="oracle.toplink.platform.database.MySQL4Platform"/>
```

Also I vaguely remember that you have to run Toplink using its Java agent in order to make it function properly with a resource local entitymanager.

I did however successfully run your example using EclipseLink (which you should use since Toplink is outdated). Only cavat was that I did not have MySQL server handy, so I ran it using H2. I used the following Maven pom.xml to resolve the dependencies:

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.randompage</groupId>
    <artifactId>sandbox</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>sandbox</name>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>EclipseLink Repo</id>
            <url>http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?r=1&amp;nf=1&amp;file=/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.130</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

and this persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="JPATestPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>
            org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider
        </provider>
        <class>org.randompage.MyEntity</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="johndoe"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="secret"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:~/.h2/testdb;FILE_LOCK=NO"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

With these settings your code ran as expected.

Comment: the main diff that I see here is you have <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>

to drop and create as opposed to just create

Comment: Do you have any pointer on that toplink bug (because that would be a bug)?

Comment: I used Toplink Essentials with GlassFish back in 2007. In those days it mapped GenerationType.AUTO to GenerationType.TABLE (see http://72.5.124.102/thread.jspa?messageID=10270235). So if you did not specifically use GenerationType.IDENTITY you had to have a sequence table handy. However I am not sure if this is still the case.

Answer (score 12):

I ran into this same problem using NetBeans IDE 6.9.

Apparently, this is a known issue. 
See
    http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Development/JPA_2.0/metamodel_api#DI_101:_20100218:_Descriptor.javaClass_is_null_on_a_container_EM_for_a_specific_case.
Also see http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=181068.

I added the last line below to persistence.xml and it fixed it for me.

```
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<!-- Add the following to work around exception issue -->
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
```

Comment: I don't know if this is a bug; I think considering as of 2018 it's still a thing, by now it's likely to be just something that the JPA spec is agnostic about. I needed to add this element (exclude-unlisted-classes) to a persistence.xml file that I had lifted from a working JPA project in Eclipse (which was using a combination of EclipseLink and Hibernate, going by the dependencies in the pom.xml) into a new bare-bones JPA project in IntelliJ that was *only* using EclipseLink (again, going by the dependencies in the pom.xml).

Answer (score 10):

As [Charles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/700389/charles) pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388755/jpa-exception-object-is-not-a-known-entity-type/5608426#5608426), the problem is not the id generation, but the persistence layer not finding the entity.

As you, I am also new to JPA. I have tried to write a "Hello World" JPA application using **`org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider`** when I got this error. The mentioned workaround also worked for me. Moreover, through trial-error I also found that to declare your entities, you must **always anotate `@entity` in each entity** and:

- if you set **`exclude-unlisted-classes`** to **`true`**, you also have to **list the entities within `class` elements in your `persistence.xml`**
- if you set **`exclude-unlisted-classes`** to **`false` the persistence layer can find the entities** regardles of the `class` element in your `persistence.xml`.

Comment: Writting a **junit** test with **`org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider`** I have also found that the `@entity` annotation is ignored and that I have to **explicitly declare the classes** to process. In other case, I also get the `is not a known entity type`.

Answer (score 2):

I use this syntax rather than type AUTO

```
@javax.persistence.Id
@javax.persistence.GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

Then, I use the simple type "long" for ID's with a lowercase l :

```
private long taskID;
```

This may be unrelated, but I also specify a different table name for my entities:

```
@javax.persistence.Entity(name = "Tasks")
public class Task implements Serializable
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried all those but i keep getting the same exception (except that the message now says [id=0] instead of [id=null]).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same exception, when deploying web applications to GlassFish v3 (which uses EclipseLink as its JPA provider).  I am not sure it's the same scenario as above - but the explanation for this bug in my case might help others :-) - turns out there's a bug in EclipseLink, when running under OSGi (which is the case in GlassFish), which leads EclipseLink to hold on to an "old" version of the entity class when re-deploying, resulting in this exception.  The bug report is [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=288141).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, whenever I get this error, I just re-start glassfish. Works everytime.

Answer (score 1):

if you are only getting this error in junit

try adding this in persistence.xml

```
<jar-file>file:../classes</jar-file>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try and leave the  definition out of the persistnce.xml The Persistence provider should than scan all classes in the classpath for @Entity annotations.

Comment: Unless when used in J2SE mode in which case it is *not* a JPA requirement to scan the CLASSPATH, besides which "exclude-unlisted-classes" is not specified anyway

Answer (score 0):

I also have to add one other item to my persistence.xml when changing class/table defs so that the EM knows to build/update tables:

```
<property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(SchemaAction=&apos;refresh&apos;)"/>
```

If I want a fresh start, I instead use:

```
<!--<property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings"
                value="buildSchema(SchemaAction='dropDB,add')"/>
                -->
```

I noticed that in your persistence.xml schema management is only set to "create tables" as opposed to drop/create, or update

Answer (score 0):

Check the class output folder of eclipse, sometimes you change the xml and it was not updated.

Answer (score 0):

The combination of deployment from within NetBeans 8.2 on Glassfish 4.1 on a Maven project with the "Debug" function of a project can cause an outdated version to be re-deployed (unclear where the fault lies).

Stop GlassFish, delete `[glassfish base]/glassfish/domains/[domain name]/generated/`, restart and redeploy.