# Object org.tts.maqraa.data.Daralquran@1e20120 is not a known entity type

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-2, eclipselink, tomcat7

I'm facing the following problem when i persist an entity using entity manager that acquired by Spring.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: org.tts.maqraa.data.Daralquran@183eae7 is not a known entity type.
javax.faces.FacesException: #{configurationChecker.check}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: org.tts.maqraa.data.Daralquran@183eae7 is not a known entity type.
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: org.tts.maqraa.data.Daralquran@183eae7 is not a known entity type.
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: org.tts.maqraa.data.Daralquran@183eae7 is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.mergeCloneWithReferences(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3484)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.mergeCloneWithReferences(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.mergeCloneWithReferences(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3455)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.mergeInternal(EntityManagerImpl.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.merge(EntityManagerImpl.java:463)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:365)
    at $Proxy8.merge(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
    at $Proxy8.merge(Unknown Source)
    at org.tts.maqraa.service.AbstractMaqraaService.store(AbstractMaqraaService.java:60)
    at org.tts.maqraa.service.DarAlQuranService.createNewDarAlQuran(DarAlQuranService.java:47)
    at org.tts.maqraa.service.test.ConfigurationChecker.check(ConfigurationChecker.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:264)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 24 more.
```

Where i'm using the following technologies

- Apache Tomcat 7.
- Eclipse Link 2.3.2.
- Spring 3.0.
- JSF 2.0 Mojarra.

Also you can find the Daralquran entity to ensure that the entity is mapped properly.

```
@Entity
public class Daralquran implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Temporal( TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="Established_Date")
    private Date establishedDate;

    @Column(name="Full_Name")
    private String fullName;

    @Column(name="Mobile_Number")
    private String mobileNumber;

    private String note;

    @Column(name="Phone_no")
    private String phoneNo;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to City
    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="city_Id")
    private City city;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Country
    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="country_Id")
    private Country country;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to User
    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="supervisor_id")
    private User user;

    //bi-directional many-to-many association to User
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="daralqurans2", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<User> users;

    public Daralquran() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getEstablishedDate() {
        return this.establishedDate;
    }

    public void setEstablishedDate(Date establishedDate) {
        this.establishedDate = establishedDate;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return this.fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getMobileNumber() {
        return this.mobileNumber;
    }

    public void setMobileNumber(String mobileNumber) {
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    }

    public String getNote() {
        return this.note;
    }

    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }

    public String getPhoneNo() {
        return this.phoneNo;
    }

    public void setPhoneNo(String phoneNo) {
        this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
    }

    public City getCity() {
        return this.city;
    }

    public void setCity(City city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public Country getCountry() {
        return this.country;
    }

    public void setCountry(Country country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return this.users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }   
    }
```

Also you can find the content of persistence.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="Maqraa">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>org.tts.maqraa.data.DarAlquranManager</class>
        <class>org.tts.maqraa.data.DoorAlquranGM</class>
        <class>org.tts.maqraa.data.QuranTeacher</class>
        <class>org.tts.maqraa.data.ScientificOfficer</class>
        <class>org.tts.maqraa.data.SystemAdmin</class>
        <class>org.tts.maqraa.data.City</class>
        <class>org.tts.maqraa.data.Country</class>
        <class>org.tts.maqraa.data.Daralquran</class>
        <class>org.tts.maqraa.data.HalaqaAchievement</class>
        <class>org.tts.maqraa.data.HalaqaAssociation</class>
        <class>org.tts.maqraa.data.Halaqa</class>
        <class>org.tts.maqraa.data.MemorizationProgram</class>
        <class>org.tts.maqraa.data.Permission</class>
        <class>org.tts.maqraa.data.Phase</class>
        <class>org.tts.maqraa.data.PhasesAttendance</class>
        <class>org.tts.maqraa.data.Recitation</class>
        <class>org.tts.maqraa.data.Role</class>
        <class>org.tts.maqraa.data.Student</class>
        <class>org.tts.maqraa.data.User</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/maqraa" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="none" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Also you can find the spring meta data configuration maqraa-module-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/maqraa" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect" />

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="Maqraa" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.SimpleLoadTimeWeaver" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="darAlquranService" class="org.tts.maqraa.service.DarAlQuranService"></bean>

    <bean id="configurationChecker" class="org.tts.maqraa.service.test.ConfigurationChecker"></bean>

</beans>
```

So, can anyone help me make the em works properly.

Thanks
Mohammed Amr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get it :),

Cause i use tomcat 7 for application running, and it is not an EE contrainer, therefore it must use "LocalEntityManagerFactory" rather than "LocalContainerEntityManagerFactory".

By this you will be able to invoke the entity manager methods and by taken a transaction in your consideration.

Totally, this is the last maqraa-module-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <!-- <context:component-scan base-package="org.tts.maqraa.data" annotation-config="true"/> -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/maqraa" />
        <property name="username" value="maqraa" />
        <property name="password" value="maqraa" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaDialect"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect" />

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
        <property name="showSql" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="Maqraa" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="configurationChecker" class="org.tts.maqraa.service.test.ConfigurationChecker"></bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />

    <!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes for eg 
        @Autowired -->
    <!-- <context:annotation-config/> -->
    <!-- enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

</beans>
```

Thanks all,
Mohammed Amr.

Answer (score 1):

This is a class loader issue, you somehow have two different versions of the same class loaded.

Ensure you have not deployed this class in two different places, and have Spring configured correctly.  Perhaps try some of the Spring examples.

Are you redeploying?  If you have not closed the old EntityManagerFactory you could get this error.  Try restarting the server.

Do all of your classes have the same error, or do some work?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to specifically  GenerationType , not use the GenerationType.Auto.Try it.I am not sure.[The same case is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388755/jpa-exception-object-is-not-a-known-entity-type)

Comment: Thanks a lot, mentioned post already seen before, with notice that i'm using IDENTITY generation type, basically i want to persist one with predefined id value.

Comment: So you can just delete the GenerationType.

Comment: Do you add @Table to specify the table you want persist.

Comment: Yes, i used the @Table and the same exception is a result.

Comment: What is the transaction management type ? `JTA` or `RESOURCE_LOCAL`. It is not given in your persistence.xml. Also can you try adding `<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>` in your persistence.xml.

Comment: I use RESOURCE_LOCAL cause there is no distributed transactions here. and neither <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes> or <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> will make it persisted.